# Get the frequency of different observations from every two columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, frequency

I have an R data frame as follow:

```
position    10164.0 10164.1 10192.0 10192.1 10316.0 10316.1 10349.0 10349.1 10418.0 10418.1
4414    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5295    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5738    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5785    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
6392    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
7727    1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
8876    1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
9018    1   1   1   2   1   0   1   1   1   1
9208    0   1   1   2   1   0   1   2   1   1
9627    0   1   1   2   1   0   1   2   0   1
```

As you can see from the 2nd column onwards the column names have a suffix (either .0 or .1)
I would like to count the number of observations in the column 1 (positions), and multiply by 2 (in this case it would be 20), and then for every column that has the same name before the suffix .0 and .1, count the number of different observations and divide by the number of observations in positions*2..

This is what I got so far with the commando in R below:

```
df = read.table(file = 'df.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
df2 = sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c("0", "1", "2"))))
write.table(df2, file='df2.tsv', quote=FALSE, sep='\t')
```

This gives me:

```
observations position   X10164.0    X10164.1    X10192.0    X10192.1    X10316.0    X10316.1    X10349.0    X10349.1    X10418.0    X10418.1
0   0   2   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   1   0
1   0   8   10  10  5   10  7   10  8   9   10
2   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   2   0   0
```

The desired output would be the transposed data frame as follow:

```
observations    0   1   2
X10164  0.1000  0.9000  0.0000
X10192  0.0000  0.7500  0.2500
X10316  0.1500  0.8500  0.0000
X10349  0.0000  0.9000  0.1000
X10418  0.0500  0.9500  0.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base R you could do:

```
a <- reshape(df,-1, dir='long', idvar = 'position')[-(1:2)]
t(prop.table(table(stack(a)),2))

       values
ind         0    1    2
  X10164 0.10 0.90 0.00
  X10192 0.00 0.75 0.25
  X10316 0.15 0.85 0.00
  X10349 0.00 0.90 0.10
  X10418 0.05 0.95 0.00
```

Comment: Hi @onyambu, thanks!
Quick question, how do I save this to a .tsv file? When I try to assign the ```t(prop.table(table(stack(a)),2))``` to a new variable so I can use the write.table, it does not work... : /

Comment: @guidebortoli first change the variable to a dataframe. ie `as.data.frame.matrix(your_results)` then you could write to tsv

Comment: do you know if doing in a different way could decrease the memory usage? Unfortunately this is giving me a a segmentation fault ```*** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f209d73b000, cause 'invalid permissions'```

Comment: Try using `cat` to only write the fisat few eows of the matrix. And see whether your tsv file is the one you want. If not, i cannot think of a way to go around the issue.